# Capitalise word's first character in Vim from insert mode, and return to the same place

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

When writing, I often find I end up with something like (where ][ is the cursor):

```
quux foo fooba][rino
```

what what I meant was

```
quux foo Fooba][rino
```

Is it possible to capitalise the `foobarino` to `Foobarino`, from insert mode, and end up in the same place, without wiping some mark that you might have set?

I know I can use something like `bgUlea` to move the start of the word, uppercase one character and move to the end and append, but I'd like to continue where I left off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace your `ea` with `gi`.

`:help gi` says:

```
Insert text in the same position as where Insert mode
was stopped last time in the current buffer.
This uses the |'^| mark.  It's different from "`^i"
when the mark is past the end of the line.
The position is corrected for inserted/deleted lines,
but NOT for inserted/deleted characters.
When the |:keepjumps| command modifier is used the |'^|
mark won't be changed.
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on @romainl's idea, here's a complete mapping, triggered by `<C-g>~`.

```
" i_CTRL-G_~        Switch case of the start of the current word from insert
"                   mode.
inoremap <C-g>~ $<BS><C-\><C-n>b~gi
```

It first ensures that the current position will be kept (by inserting a dummy character) in case of auto-indent, then leaves insert mode, jumps, performs the case switch, and finally re-enters insert mode at the original position.